# Modifying the id value of a row based on interval time threshold in date time column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am working on `geolife` [dataset](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52367&from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2Fb16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13%2Fdefault.aspx), which contains timestamped GPS track of users in a text file (`.plt`).  Each text file contains the user's GPS points for one trip. I therefore imported the dataset to `postgres` using python script.

Because the files are named with string of numbers according to the trip's start time (so for example, the file containing the trip in table below is `20070920074804.plt`), I give the trip id (`session_id`) the file name (without the extension). That's the raw GPS in this table `trajectories`.

```
 user_id |    session_id     |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt 
---------+-------------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 07:48:04+01 |  28.19737 | 113.006795 |  71
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:09+01 | 28.197685 | 113.006792 |  87
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:10+01 | 28.197685 |  113.00679 |  87
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:03:50+01 | 28.197342 | 113.007422 |  62
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:04:59+01 | 28.197108 |  113.00734 |  62
      11 |    20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:05:01+01 | 28.197088 |  113.00727 |  62
```

For analysis purposes, I created another table `trips_metrics` where I compute trip metrics from `trajectories` table and insert the result to `trip_metrics`. Among the values I compute are trip distance (`haversine`) and duration (`start time - end time`).

Then I noticed something strange, a user took `8hrs` of trip but covers a distance of `321m`. Going through the trip file thoroughly I noticed there's jump in trip's time, suggesting a break in the trip (possibly user stays for hours then continue). An example is in `row 3` and `row 4` in table above.

To get accurate trip time, I need to split trips with these cases, in a way that if the time interval between consecutive rows exceeds 30mins, it should be considered a new trip (thus new ID).

I intend to add digit `..02, ..03, ..` to the trip's current `session_id` in my `trajectories` table before actually computing trips metrics (i.e. modifying the `trajectories` table).
So for  the example in table above, I want to split it this way:

```
 user_id |    session_id     |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt 
---------+-------------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----
      11 |  20070920074804   | 2007-09-20 07:48:04+01 |  28.19737 | 113.006795 |  71
      11 |  20070920074804   | 2007-09-20 08:07:09+01 | 28.197685 | 113.006792 |  87
      11 |  20070920074804   | 2007-09-20 08:07:10+01 | 28.197685 |  113.00679 |  87
      11 |  2007092007480402 | 2007-09-20 14:03:50+01 | 28.197342 | 113.007422 |  62
      11 |  2007092007480402 | 2007-09-20 14:04:59+01 | 28.197108 |  113.00734 |  62
      11 |  2007092007480402 | 2007-09-20 14:05:01+01 | 28.197088 |  113.00727 |  62
```

Notice how I assign the `session_id` for the new trip (since the time in between is more than 30mins).

How can I do this modification or alteration to my raw GPS table (`trajectories`) in `postgres`?

**EDIT**

**A:** The first query in the answer from @GMB works, however, it gives each row I new `session_id` in the `new_session_id` column.

```
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
| user_id |   session_id   |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt | is_gap |  new_session_id  |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 07:48:04+01 | 28.19737  | 113.006795 |  71 |        |   20070920074804 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:09+01 | 28.197685 | 113.006792 |  87 |      1 | 2007092007480401 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:10+01 | 28.197685 | 113.00679  |  87 |      1 | 2007092007480402 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:03:50+01 | 28.197342 | 113.007422 |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480403 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:04:59+01 | 28.197108 | 113.00734  |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480404 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:05:01+01 | 28.197088 | 113.00727  |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480405 |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
| user_id |   session_id   |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt | is_gap |  new_session_id  |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 07:48:04+01 | 28.19737  | 113.006795 |  71 |        |   20070920074804 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:09+01 | 28.197685 | 113.006792 |  87 |        |   20070920074804 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 08:07:10+01 | 28.197685 | 113.00679  |  87 |      1 | 2007092007480401 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:03:50+01 | 28.197342 | 113.007422 |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480401 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:04:59+01 | 28.197108 | 113.00734  |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480401 |
|      11 | 20070920074804 | 2007-09-20 14:05:01+01 | 28.197088 | 113.00727  |  62 |      1 | 2007092007480401 |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+------------------+
```

The idea is to give the "emerging" trip a new id by `old_session_id + 01`. If another emerging trip is encountered it should be assigned `old_session_id + 02` and so on.

**B:** The second query with update option contains a syntax error:

```
update trajectories t
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        case when sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) > 0
            then session_id * 100 + sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)
            else session_id
        end new_session_id
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            (timestamp > lag(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp))::int is_gap
        from trajectories t
    ) t
) t1
set session_id = t1.new_session_id
where t1.session_id = t.session_id and t1.timestamp = t.timestamp

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 2: from (
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`, a cumulative sum to identify the segements, and then some way of munging the `session_id`:

```
select (case when grp >= 1 then session_id * 100 + grp
             else session_id
        end) as new_session_id,
       t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_ts < timestamp - interval '30 minute') over (partition by session_id, order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by session_id order by timestamp) as prev_ts
            from trajectories t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f7926c95b2219b815e07886548d4d7b4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Got an SQL syntax error: `ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist LINE 9:  from t`

Comment: @someone . . . That is your table name.

Comment: in this db-fiddle I illustrate the error. It appears this answer considers the filtering requirement, 30minutes interval https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=93c7f3f3bfb1355484a845d1e1990ba4

Comment: I cannot understand why `postgres` keeps complaining with sub-query alias. Can you please take a look at the db-fiddle in my comment above?

Comment: @someone . . . Oops, that should have been a window function.  I fixed the query and added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. You want to detect consecutive rows with timestamp difference that is greater than 30 minutes, and then change the `session_id` accordingly.

An option is to use `lag()`, and then a cumulative count of the gaps - you can then use that information to compute the new `session_id`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) > 0
        then session_id * 100 + sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)
        else session_id
    end new_session_id
from (
    select
        t.*,
        (timestamp > lag(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp))::int is_gap
    from trajectories t
) t
```

You can turn this to an `update` statement if needed:

```
update trajectories t
set session_id = t1.new_session_id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        case when sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) > 0
            then session_id * 100 + sum(is_gap) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)
            else session_id
        end new_session_id
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            (timestamp > lag(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp))::int is_gap
        from trajectories t
    ) t
) t1
where t1.session_id = t.session_id and t1.timestamp = t.timestamp
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I would really like to go for this answer with update option, however it needs a relook as stated in my question edit.

Comment: @someone: my bad, Postgres wants the `set` clause goes before the `from` clause. Fixed.